# Assigning FormView value to VB variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, variables

I am trying to assign a FormView value to a VB variable.

I am using code that works fine when `first_nameTextBox` is a TextBox and user enters data directly, but fails when `first_nameTextBox` is a label populated from a database via FormView.

Error I receive is BC30451: `'FormView2_first_nameTextBox' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level`.

Any help much appreciated.

The code is below;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head runat="server">
<!-- Scripting area here -->
<script runat="server" type="text/vbscript"> 
Protected Sub btnSubmit_click (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If IsPostBack Then
            Dim sc As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("relay.hostinguk.net")
            Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
            Dim msg As MailMessage = Nothing
            sb.Append("Name : " + FormView2_first_nameTextBox.Text + vbCrLf)
            Try
                msg = New MailMessage("from@company.com", _
                    "to@company.com", "Contact details for Co", _
                    sb.ToString())
                sc.Send(msg)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' something bad happened
                Response.Write("Something bad happened! - please try again")
            Finally
            Multiview1.SetActiveView(ViewConfirmation)
                If Not msg Is Nothing Then msg.Dispose()        
            End Try
    End If
    End Sub
Protected Sub Page_Load (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
    Try
    Multiview1.SetActiveView(ViewForm)
    Catch ex As Exception
                ' something bad happened
                Response.Write("Something bad happened! - please try again")
    End Try
    End If
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:MultiView runat="server" id="MultiView1">
    <asp:View runat="server" id="ViewForm"> 
            <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2bd" runat="server" DataFile="../app_data/bw_data.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_ID = 92">
            </asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:FormView runat="server" id="FormView2" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2bd" DataKeyNames="student_ID" DefaultMode="ReadOnly">
        <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:Label id="first_nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("first_name") %>' />,
        </ItemTemplate >
</asp:FormView>         
<asp:Table runat="server" id="Table2">
    <asp:TableRow runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" height="20px">
        <asp:Button id="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" onclick="btnSubmit_click" Text="Send Email"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
</asp:View>
<asp:View runat="server" id="ViewConfirmation">
        <p>An email has been sent, and copied to you, confirming all current contact details.</p>
</asp:View>
<p></p>
</asp:MultiView>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks
Ant

Comment: Since that is in `ItemTemplate`, there can be many instance of `first_nameTextBox`, so to access it you need to use `FindControl`.

Comment: @arindamnayak Thanks - I tried to add findcontrol but not working (my code?)
form appears with first_nameTextBox populated but on submit I get  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
this is what I added to include the findcontrol:

dim tb as TextBox = FindControl("FormView2_first_nameTextBox")

 
   Dim sc As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("relay.hostinguk.net")
            Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
            Dim msg As MailMessage = Nothing
   sb.Append("        Name : " + tb.Text + vbCrLf)

Comment: I was saying, you can not use `FormView2_first_nameTextBox`, rather you have to use `first_nameTextBox`, and i think you have to loop through `MultiView1` controls and use FindControl. NOTE: put up the tried code in question as an update.

Comment: I have tried 'code' Private Sub GetControlValue
   ' Find control on page.
   Dim myControl1 As Control = FindControl("Me.first_nameTextBox")
   If (Not myControl1 Is Nothing)
      ' Get control's parent.
      Dim myControl2 As Control = myControl1.Parent
      Response.Write("Parent of the text box is : " & myControl2.ID)
   Else
      Response.Write("Control not found.....")
   End If
   End Sub
but it always ends up with 'not found' - so I am not getting the right syntax - any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dim tb as TextBox = FormView2.Row.FindControl("first_nameTextBox")
sb.Append("Name : " + tb.Text + vbCrLf)
```